# Replace broken images with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to replace images that are not found, or that have width or height 1px. I managed to do this in PHP with this:

```
$imgName = $resultList->IMAGE1; // ex http://www.domain.com/image.png
  if (@file_get_contents($imgName) && $imgName !== 'h') {
    // detects the image size (NOT based on width and height attributes)
$imgNamearray = getimagesize($imgName); 
$size = $imgNamearray[3];
    if ($size == 'width="1" height="1"') {
      $imgName = $base_path . 'uploads/no-img.jpg';
    }
  } else {
    $imgName = $base_path . 'uploads/no-img.jpg';
  }
```

I tried this code in jQuery:

```
$('body').append('<div id="init"><img id="myimg" src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" /></div>');
$('#init').hide();

$('#myimg').bind("load",function(){
    alert(this.height)
})
```

which can be found in a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WMpSy/ but I am a noob in jQuery, please help me this. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't detect 1*1 pixel images.

Comment: @jfriend00 Problem is that the script from there it detects the width of the width attribute instead detecting the real image width. I am trying to detect the real width of the image. For example if I have on the image tags width and height specified, I don't want that detected, I want the real width of the data-original value image detected. (data-original is from the lazy load plugin that I am using)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to do this via javascript without changing your HTML, then you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkImg(img) {
        if (img.naturalHeight <= 1 && img.naturalWidth <= 1) {
            // undersize image here
            img.src = "upload/no-img.jpeg";
        }
    }

    $("img").each(function() {
        // if image already loaded, we can check it's height now
        if (this.complete) {
            checkImg(this);
        } else {
            // if not loaded yet, then set load and error handlers
            $(this).load(function() {
                checkImg(this);
            }).error(function() {
                // img did not load correctly
                // set new .src here
                this.src = "upload/no-img.jpeg";
            });

        }
    });
});
```

If you need support in IE8 (which doesn't have naturalHeight and naturalWidth), there are work-arounds described [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie/).

Comment: Sorry of the jquery noob question but could you give me an example on what to add on the // undersize image here, // set new .src here. I kind of need to get my php translated in jquery. From what I see here this should be what I need. Thanks again for helping

Comment: @user3467855 - what do you want to do to the undersize image?

Comment: replace it with uploads/no-img.jpg on the attribute data-original.

Comment: @user3467855 - huh?  Do you want to change the image `.src` to `"uploads/no-img.jpg"` or do you want to read something from an attribute and use that?  Which one?  If the attribute, please me more specific about what you want to do with an attribute.

Comment: Have a look at the image from here: http://jsfiddle.net/WMpSy/53/, I am using lazy load plugin, therefor the src attribute is no more, instead I replaced it with data-original attribute. And in that attribute I want to add data-original="uploads/no-img.jpg".

Comment: @user3467855 - I don't understand.  When the image doesn't load or is under size, what EXACTLY do you want to do to it?  Please describe in words what steps you want to take.  This is a frustrating question to be helping with because you keep adding more and more requirements that are NOT in your original question.

Comment: I want it to load 'upload/no-img.jpeg'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52442/discussion-between-user3467855-and-jfriend00)

Comment: @user3467855 - OK, I added setting the image to 'upload/no-img.jpeg' to my answer when there's an error.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, iterate over your images and check for their heights

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
        var height = $(this).height();
        if(height <= 1) {
            $(this).attr('src', '/your-replacement-image-path');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: All images are not necessarily loaded at document.ready time.

Comment: @jfriend00 Changed to window.load event. Thanks

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that this waits until all images are loaded before processing any of them.  So a broken image will potentially be broken for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the valid jquery code that can solve your problem. please take care of .ready and .on load

```
$('img').each(function () {
var Image = $(this);
$(window).on('load', function () {
    if (Image.width() <= 1 || Image.height() <= 1) {
        Image.attr('src', '/ImagePath');
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    Image.error(function () {
        Image.attr('src', '/ImagePath');
    });
}); });
```

Here is the working example on http://jsfiddle.net/designs5/86Tp2/