# Random fails trying to get the naturalHeight and naturalWidth of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple code where I check an image's width and height, and if it's not >= 120x90, it gets a `visibility: hidden` put on it.

```
$(".video-thumbnail").each(function() {
    var width = $(this).prop("naturalWidth");
    var height = $(this).prop("naturalHeight");

    if (width <= 120 && height <= 90) {
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});
```

The problem is this randomly fails on some page reloads (see edit below).

I think it may be a caching or browser loading delay issue.

**EDIT**

Confirmed sequence of events to reproduce:

1. Images are cached in browser
2. Modify HTML source
3. Navigate to page (not reload)

Any suggestions to run this more reliably? Maybe *force* the browser to download the image file? Not sure what that would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more reliable solution would be to use the [HTMLImageElement.decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) that returns a promise which is resolved once the full-resolution image is ready for use, an example of this is below:

```js
$(".video-thumbnail").each(function () {
  this.decode().then(() => {
      var width = $(this).prop("naturalWidth");
      var height = $(this).prop("naturalHeight");

      if (width <= 120 && height <= 90) {
          $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
      }
  }).catch((encodingError) => {
    // Do something with the error.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/121/91" class="video-thumbnail">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/121/91" class="video-thumbnail">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/119/89" class="video-thumbnail">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/121/91" class="video-thumbnail">
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an alternative method that also works as well as the one marked correct for my future reference:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $(".video-thumbnail").each(function() {
        var width = $(this).prop("naturalWidth");
        var height = $(this).prop("naturalHeight");

        if (width <= 120 && height <= 90) {
            $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

Calling `$(window).on("load"...` first is the only change. Sometimes images were not loaded with my original code.

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/93017
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8621397
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584491

Curious if there are any performance differences between this and the code in the answer marked correct. Behaviors seem to be identical.